# What's wrong with my Keil v5 compiler that target is sometimes gets created and sometimes not?

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, stm32, keil

I want to perform blinky program operation on STM32F103C8T8 using Keil v5 Compiler. I am generating C source code using STM cubemx and making Pin13 on/off with delay of 100ms. My code is [here](https://files.fm/u/n9zbag4t)

**The problem is that when I click on rebuild option the code the target is created without any error**

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcOGh.png)

and **when I click on rebuild option another time(Without any change in anything), the target is not created showing multiple errors**. The target is created when I click "rebuild" option after **N** no of trials (sometimes 1 or 2 and sometimes 100).

[image]

**I am getting mainly 2 types of errors**

**1. error :command line:#564:cannot open embedded assembler output file'':no such file or directory**

**2.error: A1620E: error writing to file :permission denied**

So how to resolve them?

Comment: I dont think that your code is responsible for this error. Maybe your project setup.

Comment: I would recommend:
- Launch KEIL with Admin privileges
- be sure the disk has free space
- path and project name contain only English charset, for example not Russian "aaa"
- likely those files blocked another program like Antivirus or Control Version System or another

Comment: @denis krasutski yes ,I have run Keil as administrator ,created same project with name as " blinky "  but nothing has changed. also i have formatted c drive of my laptop and reinstalled Windows 7 32 bit ultimate setup (earlier it was win7 professional) reinstalled keil and stm32f103c8t6 packages . But i am facing same problem .

Comment: @denis krasutski as you can see from "error image", I am getting facing mainly 2 types of errors
1. error :command line:#564:cannot open embedded assembler output file'<filename>':no such file or directory

2.error: A1620E: error writing to file <filename>:permission denied. These directories are need to be created in temp subfolders

Comment: @denis krasutski  so I manually created sub-folders in temp folder using command promt. But here very strange issue were occured .

Let me explain u

When I click rebuild all target option ,it gives error saying no directory in temp folder like p1390-2,p858-3, pbb0-2,p128c-2. So here I created directories of above names using command promt.

Then when I click rebuild all target option again, it again give same error saying no directory in temp folder but this time with different directory names like p334-3, p55c-2, p14b4-2 and p1194-3.So again I created these directories too using cmd

Comment: @denis krasutski and when I clicked rebuild all target option for 3rd time it gives same error saying no directory in temp folder but this time with another different directory names.

And this process is repeating again and again. So what should I do ?